# how specify github credential when you plublish sonar-report on a PR

Tags: github, sonarqube, pull-request

I use this command to generate only the sonnar report of the code updated by a PR:

```
sh "mvn -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9000\
                      -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview\
                      -Dsonar.github.pullRequest=${env.BRANCH_NAME.substring(3)}\
                      -Dsonar.github.repository=***********\
                      -Dsonar.github.login=${env.GH_LOGIN} \
                      -Dsonar.github.password=${env.GH_PASSWORD} sonar:sonar \
                      -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9000 \
                      -Dsonar.login=****** \
                      -Dsonar.password=*******
```

the issue is that I've this stack:

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project jenkinscraft: Failed to execute project builder: 
org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder: This operation requires a credential but none is given to the GitHub constructor
```

Any Idea how I can specify the credential?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `sonar.github.oauth` property to specify the [personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/). This is documented in the [GitHub plugin page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin).